# How to remove an element by class in an iFrame

Tags: html, class, dom, iframe

i want to remove a link (with a tag) in after iframe loaded

this link has a class and the name of class is : "footPrint"

how should i do ?

can i remove a specific class after iframe loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to access Iframe's content if they are not in the same domain. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).
I am, of course, guessing that you are loading an external source... 
As well you can't access (and change) CSS propriety inside that iFrame.

There is anyway a chance to do that, being little experienced with Javascript, trought [this interesting library](https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole/) on active develop...